# Velocity - How to avoid ParseErrorException when using jQuery?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json, velocity

I'm trying to add a jQuery post to some JavaScript on a web page. The entire page is built up of several Velocity templates. Everything has been fine until I've tried to add the jQuery post, now I get:

```
org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Encountered "," at line 282, column 24 of /WEB-INF/velocity/www/comments.vm
Was expecting one of:
    "(" ...
    <RPAREN> ...
    <ESCAPE_DIRECTIVE> ...
~~~snip~~~
```

Line 282 is `$.post(...` and column 24 appears to be the first "," character. Initially I had the JSON on this line, but I moved it up (to the `var myJSONObject ...` line)as I thought the error related to invalid JSON (tabs at the start of the line gave a misleading column number).

```
var myJSONObject = {"body": "", "action": "postcomment", "submitted": "true", "ajax": "true"};
myJSONObject.body = $("body").val();
$.post("$!{articleurl}", myJSONObject, function(result){            
    btn.textContent='Comment sent successfully.';  
});
```

---

**Minor Update**

I changed the following lines:

```
var url = "$articleurl";

$.post(url, myJSONObject, function(result){
~~~snip~~~
```

The parse exception still focuses on the first "**,**". I'm assuming the issue is that Velocity thinks it should be able to resolve $.post - when in fact, it's jQuery. I've used jQuery in other Velocity VM templates without any problem. Is there a way to get Velocity to ignore certain lines / statements when parsing?

---

**Update 2**

I found [this link](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#escapingvalidvtlreferences) about escaping references in Velocity, but it does not resolve my issue. Adding a "**\**" before `$.post` gives me the exact same error, but the column is one extra, because of the character added at the start of the line.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can wrap your javascript with `#[[ ... ]]#` which tells Velocity to not parse the enclosed block (new in Velocity 1.7)

```
#[[ 
<script>
    ...
</script>
]]#
```

Comment: The other downside of this is that you'll have noticed I use a few Velocity variables within the script.

Comment: @Mikaveli I usually initiate all js variables that come from velocity in a separated script block above.

Comment: That sounds like the better approach, I'll do some refactoring to improve readability / maintainability. :D

Comment: @Mikaveli You can also just write `jQuery` instead of `$`

Comment: Thank you very much for this useul answer. You've made my day.

Answer (score 9):

Ok, there appears to be two solutions for this:

First, with jQuery we can just avoid using the global alias $ and instead use the jQuery object directly:

```
jQuery.post(url, myJSONObject, function(result){
~~~snip~~~
```

In my case, the above works great. But I suspect in other scenarios (non-jQuery) this may not be possible. In which case, we can 'hide' our character within a valid Velocity reference like this:

```
#set( $D = '$' )
${D}
```

Source: http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#escapinginvalidvtlreferences

I'd still like to know why the backslash escape didn't work, but the above will at least get me moving again. :)

Comment: the backslash is for escaping actual references, not things that cause parse errors.  think of the backslash as something that only applies after parsing.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a **bug** in version 1.6.x, because it works fine in 1.7(If it did not, please tell me, I test it many times..), according to the reference, the `$` takes effect only when it is followed by `a-zA-Z`. I want to try do debug what happened really, but the translation code is generated by Java CC tool, it is too hard to recognize the logic...

Answer (score 0):

you must create a js file with your javascript code
and import your js file into your vm code

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't get it to work with any of the other fixes like escaping "$" in velocity unfortunately. I got it working by loading an external js-file with the jQuery instead of writing jQuery directly in velocity. Worked out for me at least, hope it helps someone :)

/björn